# How to save data from editable grid in ExtJS in a json file and refresh grid with changes?

Tags: extjs, grid, extjs4.2

I have an editable grid in ExtJS. I fetch the data from a json file and am trying to save it back to it after editing. After editing, I click on save and call Store.sync() but it makes no change in the JSON file and the grid is refreshed back to the state prior to editing. I am a newbie to ExtJS. What am I missing here, how to make it work?

```
    Ext.define('User', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    fields: [ 
          {name: 'Pricelist', type: 'string'},
          {name: 'Productfamily', type:'string'},
          {name: 'Producttype', type:'string'},
          {name: 'Productsubgroup', type: 'string'},
          {name: 'Item', type: 'string'},
          {name: 'Level', type: 'string'},
          {name: 'Factor', type:'string'},
          {name: 'Factorvalue', type: 'string'},
          {name: 'Effstrtdate', type: 'string'},
          {name: 'Effenddate', type: 'string'},
          {name: 'Comments', type: 'string'}             
        ]
    });

    var userStore = Ext.create('Ext.data.JsonStore', {
    model: 'User',
    proxy: {
       type: 'ajax',
       url: '/pwbench/form/products/fctrmgmt/data.json',
       api: {
        read: '/pwbench/form/products/fctrmgmt/data.json',
            update: '/pwbench/form/products/fctrmgmt/data.json'
       }, 
       reader: {
            type: 'json',
       }
    },
    autoLoad: true

    });

    var grid = Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
    renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
    store: userStore,
    title: 'Application Users',
    selType: 'cellmodel',
    plugins: [
        Ext.create('Ext.grid.plugin.CellEditing', {
        clicksToEdit: 1
        })
    ],
    columns: [....      
    ],
    tbar: [
       {
           text: 'Save',
           handler: function() {
               userStore.sync();
               userStore.load();

           }
       }
    ],
    });

    Ext.application({
   requires: ['Ext.container.Viewport'],
       name: 'ExtGrid',
       launch: function() {
            Ext.create('Ext.container.Viewport', {
            items: grid,
            width: 800,
            height: 600
       });

    }
    });
```

Comment: I am able to fetch the updated records by using getUpdatedRecords after making changes in the grid but how do I save them?

Comment: Setup writer in proxy config. See [official example](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.0/extjs-build/examples/writer/writer.html)

Comment: Do I just include the following under proxy config?

writer {
      type: 'json'
}

I added this, but not working. What else do I need to add?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't just "update the json" without any other interaction. Imagine how big of a security flaw that would be, where any http request could just update a file on your server.

You need some server side technology, PHP/Java/.NET/other to take the response and write it to the file. There are plenty of examples of this in the Ext SDK download.

Comment: Thanks! Let me check that.